# Google Chrome cache - can I view images/snapshots of webpages?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cache

I was working on WordPress writing up blogs, but unknown to me was the the WordPress server for my website was down. so I was essentially working into nothing, the blogs are lost, and the revised editions are not helpful.

Is it possible to go through my Google Chrome cache and see if there are snapshots of the pages i was working on?

I'm trying a cache viewer website at the minute with little success, and I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Cache contains data that browser has downloaded, but not what happens later (like what you enter in form fields). There's no way to recover your post from cache.

You can install Lazarus extension to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: gutting, but at least i know now. thank you.